# Search group in bin text with regex

Tags: regex

I need to found the groups in a big text by knowing of:

- Word that define the start of a group
- Word contained in the group
- Word that  define the finish of group group

the start word is : **begin**
the contained word is: **536916223**
the finish word is: **end**

> On the text , in the bottom, I need to find 2 groups..

I have tried to use:

```
\bbegin.*(\n*.*)*536916223(\n*.*)*\bbegin
```

but if I will be try to use the previous regex on the site "http://regexr.com/"
it respond with timeout... and I think the regex is not very good :(

The text is:

```
begin active link
   export-version : 11
   actlink-order  : 2
   wk-conn-type   : 1
   schema-name    : HelpDesk
   actlink-mask   : 1
   actlink-control: 750000002
   enable         : 1
   action {
      set-field   : 0\536916222\101\4\1\1\
   }
   errhandler-name: 
end
begin active link
   export-version : 11
   actlink-order  : 2
   wk-conn-type   : 1
   schema-name    : HelpDesk
   actlink-mask   : 1
   actlink-control: 610000092
   enable         : 1
   permission     : 0
   action {
      id          : 536916223
      focus       : 0
      access-opt  : 1
      option      : 0
   }
   action {
      set-field   : 0\536916222\101\4\1\1\
   }
   errhandler-opt : 0
   errhandler-name: 
end
begin active link
   actlink-order  : 12
   wk-conn-type   : 1
   schema-name    : HelpDesk
   actlink-mask   : 2064
   enable         : 1
   permission     : 0
   action {
      id          : 536916223
      focus       : 0
      access-opt  : 1
      option      : 0
   }
   action {
      set-field   : 0\536916222\101\4\1\1\
   }
   errhandler-opt : 0
   errhandler-name: 
end
```

Can someone suggest me a optimize regex for this work?

Regards,
Vincenzo

Comment: In what language / environment?

Comment: `(\n*.*)*` might be the culprit here

Comment: Are `begin` and `end` appear at the start of lines? Does  the `end` trailing delimiter occupy the whole line?

Comment: Also, please note that only my regex extracts the last-level `begin-end`, meaning that if there are enclosed, nested `begin-end` blocks, my regex won't extract those. That would require a regex with recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an unrolled [**tempered greedy token**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed):

```
/\bbegin.*(?:\n(?!begin|end(?:$|\n)).*)*\b536916223\b.*(?:\n(?!begin|end(?:$|\n)).*)*\nend/g
```

or a shorter version if we add `MULTILINE` modifier:

```
/^begin.*(?:\n(?!begin|end$).*)*\b536916223\b.*(?:\n(?!begin|end$).*)*\nend$/gm
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jM0jO5/3) (a [version with MULTILINE modifier](https://regex101.com/r/jM0jO5/4))

*Details*:

- `\bbegin` - a word `begin`  (a word boundary `\b` can be added after it for surer matches)
- `.*` - the rest of the line after `begin`
- `(?:\n(?!begin|end(?:$|\n)).*)*` - the unrolled tempered greedy token `(?:(?!\n(?:begin|end(?:$|\n)))[\s\S])*` matching any sequence but `begin` at the beginning of a line and `end` as a whole line
- `\b536916223\b` - the whole word `536916223`
- `.*` - the rest of the line after the number
- `(?:\n(?!begin|end(?:$|\n)).*)*` - another unrolled tempered greedy token
- `\nend` - the `end` word after a newline (a `(?:$|\n)` can be added after it for surer matches)

Comment: Ok, seems like I adjusted the explanation. Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Would you please say why did you used `$` in alternation of your first proposed regex?

Comment: The first one is not using the multiline mode.

Comment: I know I mean what is the reason behind it

Comment: Because `end` can be both at the end of the string or before a newline.

Comment: Isn't *last* part of regex `\nend` enough for matching a `end` delimiter at the very end of the string?

Comment: In my regex, I decided to add a check that `end` occupies the whole line. I did not add (?:$|\n) in the pattern at the top, but I added a remark in the explanations.

Comment: If it is totally unnecessary you may want simply to admit that.

Comment: If I remove it, a block cannot have a line starting with `end`. I only consider the whole line equal to `end` as a trailing block delimiter.

Comment: Sorry I'm not against you, I have up-voted your answers many times and learnt different things from them but I don't like this kind of rationalizing.

Comment: I like when regex matches what it should: no more no less.

Comment: That doesn't seem valid. Like you cared about some lines that probably could have `end` at the beginning of them (e.g. `endItIsButNotEndOfBlock`) **but not** lines that could have `begin` at the beginning (e.g. `beginningOfANormalLine` ). If you mean it *no more no less* (which I don't get it really) you should care about many other *hypothetical* things too that are never going to happen: *there are spaces at the beginning of each line of a block if you look closer.*

Answer (score 0):

The `.*(\n*.*)*` part is a bit complicated and results in many backtrack.
Since `.` does not match whitespace character, we can use a global wildcard such as `[\S\s]` to match any character. Another possible improvement (and possibly correction) is to use lazy match, i.e. `*?`
The following pattern seems to work fine
`\bbegin[\S\s]*?536916223[\S\s]*?\bend`

Answer (score 0):

Regex (with `m` modifier set):

```
^begin(?:(?!^end)[\s\S])*?536916223[\s\S]*?end
```

Explanation:

```
^begin              # Match `begin` at start of line
(?:                 # Start of non-capturing group (a)
    (?!^end)[\s\S]      # A character which is not followed by `end` delimiter
)*?                 # Zero or more times (un-greedy)
536916223           # Up to special word
[\s\S]*?            # Match any other characters
end                 # Up to first `end` delimiter
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/kL6wK7/2)

**Much more efficient version** - (with `m` modifier set):

```
^begin.*(?:\n(?!^end).*)*536916223(?:.*\n)*?^end
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/kL6wK7/4)